# Error found when loading /etc/profile and mysql

Tags: gnome, permissions, mysql, session

Running Ubuntu Gnome 19.04 and getting the following popup. (sorry, computer not responding for proper screenshot)

[image]

So far I tried reinstalling the Ubuntu Gnome Desktop, even mysql-common.

What was changed before this error: I moved the datadir of MariaDB10.4 to a different drive, but that was 4 days ago, and since I rarely reboot I did not notice this problem until today when I had to restart.

The folder exists with permissions:

```
drwx------ 2 mysql root    4096 Αυγ   1 23:23 auth_pam_tool_dir
```

and the siblings on the same directory are `root:root` so is ., .. is mysql:mysql

Now I have to use the ugly (sorry) Cinnamon desktop and wait for a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the permissions on the folder to

```
sudo chmod 0755 /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/auth_pam_tool_dir/
```

and also changing the permissions on the executable to

```
sudo chmod 4755 /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/auth_pam_tool_dir/auth_pam_tool
```

Seems to have fixed it. Did a couple of restarts and I can get to Ubuntu Gnome Desktop.

Details:
https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-19876

Comment: Hi, got into the same problem. How should I login to change the permission? Nothing works here